# Strange layout problem that changes with input (Chrome only)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout

I have a page that if viewed with Chrome shows weird problems with layout.
**Other browsers do not have this problem.**

Vertical position of element containing text **changes randomly**. You have to look at the example to understand what happens exactly.

Try for example to enter a "**y**" letter into the filter field, layout messes up. With other letter layout behaves correctly. How can I fix it? Can you suggest a workaround?

Debug didn't help, it seems a Chrome bug. Can you confirm?

```js
function myfilter(list, filt) {
  origin = document.getElementById(list)
  var label = origin.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
    var supspan = label[i].parentNode
    var subspan = label[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
    if (subspan.lastChild.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(filt.toLowerCase()) > -1)
      supspan.style.display = 'inline'
    else {
      supspan.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
BODY {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px
}

DIV.lists {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 230px;
  height: 190px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <div id="x-99" class="box1">
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>An eagle is flying hign on mount Kailash</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>BTRHGG TWWS to get together first six months - DAY 1</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>BTRHGG TWWS to get together first six months - DAY 2</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>AGC Opening 2015 – The strength to be independent</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>Contributes antiwar nuclear</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>Contributes course dfa number 1</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>Elements for Risk analysis and risk management</span></label><br></span>
    <span><label><input type="checkbox" style="display:none"><span>Elements for the comprehension scenery</span></label><br></span>
  </div>
  Filter: <input type="text" oninput="myfilter('x-99',this.value)">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks isherwood but this question is not a duplicate, this problem is related to Chrome browser only, while on Firefox and Edge it works correctly.